# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in modal

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

In a modal dialog, I show values in separate spans, which are coming from an object (example: skill1, skill2, skill3). Everything works well. However, I get an error message `TypeError: Can not read property' split 'of undefined in App.js`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="matchSkills">
    <span class="tags t-vg ion-trophy icon-tag matchTagVg"
          ng-repeat="skillsVeryGood in (skillsVeryGood | commaSplit)"> 
      {{ skillsVeryGood }}
    </span>                 
    <span class="tags t-g ion-ribbon-a icon-tag matchTagG"
          ng-repeat="skillsGood in (skillsGood | commaSplit)">
     {{ skillsGood }}
    </span>                   
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
// comma separating filter

.filter('commaSplit', function() {
  return function(input) {
    //console.log(input);
    var ar = input.split(','); // this will make string an array 
    return ar;
  };
})
```

**controller.js**

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/infoPerson.html', function(modalPersonInfo) {
    $scope.modalPersonInfo = modalPersonInfo;

}, {
    scope: $scope,
});


// Open the modal Person Info

$scope.PersonInfo = function(chat) {
    $scope.skillsGood = chat.skillsGood;
    $scope.skillsVeryGood = chat.skillsVeryGood;
    $scope.modalPersonInfo.show(chat);
};
```

Comment: Change your code like this if(input!=undefined){var ar = input.split(',');}

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score -1):

I would add a check to ensure that `input` has a value. You could do something like:

```
var ar = input ? input.split(',') : [];
```